# Do Quark confinement prevents proving strings?

Tags: string-theory, quantum-chromodynamics

In baryons like protons,neutrons;isolated quark doesn't exist due to quark confinement. We will need an infinite energy to pull quarks apart.Even if we try to pull them apart there will be pair production of quark-anti quark matter i.e., mesons due to quark confinement. So this confinement   always prevents existence of isolated quarks;so hypothesized strings in quarks could ever be proven?

Comment: If string theory can uniquely predict the parameters of the standard model, it will be perfectly acceptable despite confinement. The reason why it's useless is because it can't do it.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. String theory does not actually talk about "strings in quarks".

Answer (score 2):

Confinement is a low energy phenomenon. By this I mean that as you increase the energy with which you probe the properties of quarks they appear more and more like free particles. This property is called [asymptotic freedom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_freedom).

If we had some hypothetical accelerator capable of doing experiments at energies where stringy effects start to be significant it would be operating at energies where the quarks appear free, and therefore confinement would not be an issue.

So no, confinement does not mean we can never measure string effects for quarks.

Comment: But we can't observe strings in quarks due to confinement. So if confinement is true this makes string theory never proven.am I right on this sir?

Comment: No, because we can observe the properties of quarks even though they are confined.

Comment: @SrikanthReddy: I've rewritten my answer to make it clearer

Comment: What does string theory predict for quarks?